# Flutter Android Notifications Problem: No activity found to launch app

Tags: flutter, flutter-notification

I have created an app where I am listening to notifications.

This is the background handler:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
 
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}
```

Once I send a notification, this is the error I get in the console:

```
E/FA      (10207): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See ...
W/FirebaseMessaging(10207): Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.
I/flutter (10207): Handling a background message: 0:1696623184455491%f48e3641f48e3641
W/FirebaseMessaging(10207): No activity found to launch app
```

What am I doing wrong? I see that the notification triggers something but I cannot manage to make the phone show the notification. What has to be done?

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You must to create the Android Notification Channel before trigger any notification. I use [this package to create the channels](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#displaying-a-notification).

```dart
final androidLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      localNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();
  await androidLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotificationChannel(
    AndroidNotificationChannel(
      "channel id",
      "channel name",
      description: "Description",
      importance: Importance.low,
    ),
  );
```